# Local variable 'tools' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python. I'm currently creating a simple program. Can you guys educate me how **global keyword** works? I ran the code and after typing 3 to select the shutdown option I'm being greeted by local variable 'tools' referenced before assignment. It's been hours and I can't figure this out. Thanks for the help guys.

This is the error code:

You can see the code [here](https://controlc.com/d0b0a821). I don't want to put the entire code in here because it's too long.

Comment: You don't need to post the entire code here, but you need to post a [mre].

Comment: You shouldn't define functions inside `if` blocks. Define the functions at top-level, and call them in the the `if` conditions.

Comment: Welcome. Please take a look at [ask]. As @Barmar said, don't post the entire code, just what is relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/. Please note that this is *not a discussion forum*; we *do not care* about your level of expertise (and could guess anyway); we *do* care about having a *researched, specific* question. This is not the place to learn about broad topics; that's what [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) and [search engines](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+global+keyword) are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, at the very end of the program, you are calling `tools`(Line 165). However, because `tools` was defined inside of an if block that wasn't executed, that function doesn't exist. What you need to do is move the definition of `tools` outside of the if-statement to the top level so that it is can be executed anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and do not try to answer questions that don't meet our standards.